# JSP & Mysql - finding a specific item in database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to implement a method *find* that will search a book in the mysql database bearing the isbn I have entered in the the text field of JSP. My issue is that how do I correctly implement the *find* method in the ManagerBook.java class and how do I display the book found on the same JSP page (if the book is found in the db) by calling the *find* method. Have a look at my codes written so far:

**ManagerBook.java**

```
public int findBook(int isbn) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

String find = "SELECT * from boo WHERE isbn = ?";
Statement stt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery(find);

while(rs.next()){
    int isbn1 = rs.getInt("isbn");
    String title1 = rs.getString("title");
    Book b2 = new Book();
    b2.setIsbn(isbn1);
    b2.setTitle(title1);

}

con.close();
stt.close();
rs.close();

return b2;
}
```

**Book.java**

```
package book;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {

    private int isbn;
    private String title;

    @Id
    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

 }
```

**find.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.*, book.*" %>

    <jsp:useBean id = "bm" class="book.ManagerBook" scope = "session"/> 

    <%
        int success = 0;

    Boolean submitted = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("submitted"));
    if(submitted){
        int isbn = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("isbn"));      
        success = bm.findBook(isbn);
    }
    %>

    <h1> Welcome to ABC Library</h1>

    <form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Enter Details </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="isbn"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="find" value="find"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
</form> 

        <%
        if((success == 1) && (submitted)){%> <h3> The book is found</h3> <br>


        <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
    <h2>Book Found</h2>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><h3>ISBN</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Title</h3></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
        <td><%=bm.getIsbn() %></td>
        <td><%=bm.getTitle() %></td>
    </tr>
        </table>    

    <%} else if (submitted){ %>
        <h3> Book not found</h3>
        <% } %>
```

Thanks & Kind Regards.. :)

Comment: use `ajax` with `jquery` and make a call to `servlet`. In `servlet` write your search code.

Comment: Not for the time being. 
The issue lies in the ManagerBook.java and find.jsp

Comment: No what you are doing is wrong. you suppose to avoid `java` code in  `jsp` and db logic should be in separate class. next, what is the use of `hidden` form field?

Comment: Actually, I've just started with jsp. Yes, the db is in the a separate class. 
The use of the hidden field is to display the result retrieved from the db on the same JSP.  Can you advise me how to call the find method in the JSP and correct same in the ManagerBook.java ?

Comment: first, whats the problem with your existing code? any errors?

Comment: Yes,, I am unable to return b2 in ManagerBook.java and no idea how to correctly call the function in JSP and display the results.

Answer (score 2):

Your findBook method has return type as int, but it is actually returning an object of type Book. So it won't compile.

You can declare an instance variable of type Book in ManagerBook class, say

```
Book searchedBook;
```

Now in your findBook method, set this variable value to the book returned by your SQL query and return an int value 1.

In JSP, you can use :

```
    <tr>
        <td><%=bm.getSearchedBook().getIsbn() %></td>
        <td><%=bm.getSearchedBook().getTitle() %></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: The variable `b2` has to be declared outside the loop, but does not need to be an instance variable. +1 for avoiding any discussion about using those kind of code inside JSPs. %-)

Comment: Hey there.. 
Can you please re-arrange the correction of code in ManagerBook.java and same in JSP? I am a bit confused of what you did there :/
Thanks

Comment: Where does getSearchedBook() comes from?

Comment: getSearchedBook() is getter method for searchedBook variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ManagerBook` class, you need to create a prepared statement instead and then bind variables to it, before you execute the statement. In your original code, you never enter the `isbn` number into the query.

You also need to change the return type of your method to `Book`. `public int findBook(...)` should be `public Book findBook(...)`. And create the `Book` object outside the `while` loop.

```
public Book findBook(int isbn) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    String find = "SELECT * from boo WHERE isbn = ?";
    PreparedStatement stt = con.prepareStatement(find);
    stt.setInt(1, isbn);
    ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery();

    Book b2 = new Book();

    while (rs.next()){
        b2.setIsbn(rs.getInt("isbn");
        b2.setTitle(rs.getString("title");
    }
    // If more than one entry (row) is returned from the query,
    // b2 will only represent the last one.

    // Close these in reverse order of creation
    rs.close();
    stt.close();       
    con.close();

    return b2;
}
```

If no row is found, the method will return an empty, uninitialized, Book object.

Or, adapting the method for your code in `find.jsp`:

```
public int findBook(...) {
    ...
    ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery();
    int found = 0;
    if (rs.next()) {
        found = 1;
    }
    ...
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Confused about what you said too :/

Comment: @JamesSmith: I've added an example.

Comment: I had edited my code as follows : http://pastebin.com/5mJ26jLN

Now, how do I call it my JSP and display the appropriate results when I click the button find ?

Comment: How do I retrieve the result in my JSP ?

Comment: Roger Please help me to display the result in my JSP based on my code above :/

Comment: No you are understanding my question. How do I display the book that has been retrieved from the db in my JSP based on your codes above?

Comment: See the answer from @AmolBinwade, it gives you a great hint about that.

Comment: I cant understand where getSearchedBook() comes from :/

Comment: It's custom to create getters and setters for fields in a class. The suggestion was to create a field `searchedBook`. With that you usually create the two methods `public Book getSearchedBook()` and `public void setSearchedBook(Book someBook)`.

Answer (score 0):

your coding is having many issues.

1. Use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` to avoid `sql injection` and make `performance` fast.
2. Instead of `while(rs.next())`, use `if(rs.next())` to check the condition
3. `Book b2 = new Book();`, it should be outside of the loop (beginning of the method).
4. last `return` the `b2`.
5. Change the `return` type of `findBook(-)` method from `int` to `Book`. Since its returning `b2`, object of `Book`.

Instead of

```
 public int findBook(int isbn) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
 return b2;
 }
```

use

```
public Book findBook(int isbn) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
Book b2=new Book();
....................
return b2;
}
```

6. In `JSP`, instead of `success = bm.findBook(isbn);` use `Book bm = bm.findBook(isbn);`. Since `return` type of `findBook()` method is now `Book`.

Comment: How can return type of `find` be `Book` ? Its giving an error. 

Your answer is not clear in my mind :/

Comment: `public Book findBook(int isbn)`.

Comment: I had edited my code as follows : http://pastebin.com/5mJ26jLN

Now, how do I call it my JSP and display the appropriate results when I click the button find ?

Comment: Seems error-free till now. 
But how do I display the book that has been found on the JSP ?

Comment: I am still a beginner ! 

With all these codes around trying to bring a solution, I am now much more confused. 
Can you provide a simple step to get the result correctly ?