# Calling a function from a java class in a JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a stateless session java class known as ManagerBook.java where I have the following method:

```
public int findBook(int isbn) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

String find = "SELECT * from book WHERE isbn = ?";
PreparedStatement stt = con.prepareStatement(find);
stt.setInt(1, isbn);
ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery();

int found = 0;
if (rs.next()) {
    int isbn1 = rs.getInt("isbn");
    String title = rs.getString("title");
    Book b1 = new Book();
    b1.setIsbn(isbn1);
    b1.setTitle(title); 

    found = 1;
}
con.close();
stt.close();
rs.close();
return found;
}
```

**Update 1 - The Book.java class**

```
package book;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

 @Entity
 public class Book {

    private int isbn;
    private String title;

    @Id
    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

  }
```

Next, in my JSP page I want to retrieve the data of the isbn number that I have entered in my input field. It should display me the isbn and other details as per my sql query in ManagerBook.java class. When I click the submit button, it should display the ISBN and Title of the book bearing the ISBN number that I have entered in the input field. Please help. How do I get the ISBN and tile in my JSP ? Thanks

**find.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.*, book.*" %>

    <jsp:useBean id = "bm" class="book.ManagerBook" scope = "session"/> 

    <%
        int success = 0;

    Boolean submitted =   Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("submitted"));
    if(submitted){
        int isbn = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("isbn"));      
        success = bm.findBook(isbn);
    }   

    %>

    <h1> Welcome to ABC Library</h1>

    <form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Enter Details </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="isbn"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="find" value="find"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
</form> 

        <%
        if((success == 1) && (submitted)){%> 
            <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
    <h2>Book Found</h2>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><h3>ISBN</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Title</h3></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
        <td><%=b1.getIsbn%></td>
        <td><%=b1.getTitle() %></td>
    </tr>
        </table>    

    <%} else if (submitted){ %>
        <h3> Book Not Found</h3>
        <% } %>
```

**Update 3 - The error is here**

```
   <tr>
        <td><%=b1.getIsbn%></td>
        <td><%=b1.getTitle() %></td>
    </tr>
        </table>    

    <%} else if (submitted){ %>
        <h3> Book Not Found</h3>
        <% } %>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665214/jsp-mysql-finding-a-specific-item-in-database

Comment: @Satya - Lol.. You must understand that with all struggles that I am trying to resolve this issue. That's why asking for help !

Answer (score 0):

In form, specify the action as the jsp itself.

```
<form action="find.jsp" method="GET">
```

So whenever the form will be submitted,it will redirect it to the same jsp.
In request object,isbn number will be present which will be passed to that function defined in java class.

[Refer this link for more detailed explanation.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JSP/0090__JSP_Form_Processing.htm)

To get isbn number and Book name Use

```
<%if((success == 1) && (submitted)){%> 
Book Found
ISBN Number=<%=request.getparameter("isbn")%>
Book Name=<%=bm.getBookName()%><!-- getBookName() method in ManagerBook -->
<%}
else
{
%>
Book Not found
<%}%>
```

Comment: That is okay. I have managed to achieved this by using a hidden field. 

But what I am unable to achieve is displaying the ISBN & title of the book that I have set in the ManagerBook.java.. Jelp

Comment: You can write one more method in ManagerBook.java which will be invoked if success is 1 and that method will return book name.So You can add a scripylet in your jsp where you can check if book found then show isbn and bookname.

Comment: I have added.. Please review my codes. Why can't I get the results to be displayed ?

Comment: Don't use b1 as a reference.It shud be bm.Try the code which i added..i hope that helps.